# Get Image file from HTTP Response Body

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, multipart

Android Client send a request to the server.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://test.com/test");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

and then received response from server like below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2012 10:59:35 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; type="image/jpeg"; boundary="simple_boundary"; start="<image>"; start-info="image/jpeg"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

2000

--simple_boundary

Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <image>

......JPEG Binary Code Here.....

--simple_boundary
```

How can I get the Image(binary) from the response.

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

(InputStream)is contains boundary and content information also.

```
--simple_boundary

Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <image>

......JPEG Binary Code Here.....

--simple_boundary
```

How can I get pure Image binary data.
And it's possible??

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Comment: It doesn't work. InputStream contains not only binary data but also content information.

Answer (score 0):

The request content is split and encoded, therefore it is far from easy deal with it.

I used [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/index.html) years ago to process this kind of request (e.i. multipart), this library simplified the process greatly.

In the [getting started](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) section you could find several examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need a http parser to read the message body.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/io/HttpResponseParser.html